# Conflicts with Symfony2 AsseticBundle and the 'non existing routes'

Tags: php, symfony

Assetic doesn't work very wells with this tag:

```
{% stylesheets output='/style/app.css'
    '@VendorBundle/Resources/style/main.css'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

If I use it, it's like Assetic doesn't know what to do with this. In config_dev `use_controller` is true. I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I just get this:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_aca6c7a_0" as such route does not exist.") in "VendorBundle:Section:template.html.twig".

Maybe some cache issue? I don't know what I can try...

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. In my case clearing **app/cache** and **app/logs** solved the issue.

Comment: Worked beautifully for me !

Answer (score 3):

Just add the name of your bundle in the config.yml file, so it can have the rights to create files.

```
assetic:
    bundles:        [ VendorBundle ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved by adding a route in routing_dev.php

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```